# In Java, is it possible to clear a bit?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

In Java, is it possible to clear a bit using bitwise operations?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

yes, using

```
bits & ~(1 << n)
```

where **bits** is an int/long and **n** is the n-th bit to be cleared.

(this is a useful blog post: [**low level bit hacks you absolutely must know**](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/))

Comment: Care needs to be taken if n is > 31, the “1” needs to be “1L” in that case otherwise the shift operation will only use the five lowest bits of n. (See JLS, § 15.19.)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to dfa's answer would be to use a [BitSet datastructure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). It supports operations such as AND, OR and XOR.

```
var bitset = new BitSet(K);    // Initialize a bitset with K digits.
var nthBit = bitset.get(n);    // Get Nth bit (true/false).

bitset.clear(n);               // Clears N'th bit to false.
bitset.set(n);                 // Sets N'th bit to true.
bitset.flip(n);                // Toggles N'th bit.
```

In your case, you'll be looking for `bitset.clear(n)`.

If you have to use integers, then set value using `bits |= (1 << N)` and as 
dfa mentioned, clear using: `bits &= ~(1 << N)`.